# Axios: method is called before interceptor

Tags: javascript, axios

I am trying to update access token using refresh tokens. I am using axios interceptors to call the `/refresh`endpoint which returns a new access token. I am setting the token and refresh token in local storage. however, when the token is expired, the `getAll` method is called before the response interceptor. the token does get updated in the local storage after I call the `/refresh` endpoint in the response interceptor, but in the `getAll` method, the token that's set in the header is still the previous expired token. When I refresh the page though, the new token is set in the header and it works as expected. when I see the server console, it shows the `/patients` endpoint is called before the `/refresh` endpoint. I am calling the `getAll` method when the component mounts.

axios interceptor code:

```
import { getFromLS } from "./localStorage";

const baseURL = "http://localhost:4200/api" 
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL,
});

instance.interceptors.request.use((request: AxiosRequestConfig) => {
  axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = "";
  delete axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"];
  if (getFromLS("token")) {
    if(request.headers) {
      request.headers.Authorization = getFromLS("token");
    }
  }
  return request;
});

instance.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => response,
  (error) => {
    const originalRequest = error.config;

    if (
      error.response.status === 401 &&
      originalRequest.url === `${baseURL}/refresh`
    ) {
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }

    if (error.response.status === 401 && !originalRequest._retry) {
      originalRequest._retry = true;
      instance
        .post("/refresh", {
          body: {
            id: Number(getFromLS("user")),
            refreshToken: getFromLS("refreshToken"),
          },
        })
        .then((response) => {
          const newToken = response.data.data.newAccessToken;
          localStorage.setItem("token", newToken);
          instance.defaults.headers.common[
            "Authorization"
          ] = `Bearer ${newToken}`;
          return instance(originalRequest);
        })
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

export default instance;
```

the `getAll` method which uses the above axios instance:

```
 get: (url: string) => instance.get<IPatientResponse>(url).then(responseBody)
 getAll: (): Promise<IPatientResponse[]> => get("/patients"),
```

Comment: Curious if you figured this out. I’m having this exact problem.

Comment: @user1464317 No. did you ask chat gpt yet?

Comment: Actually yes. Just now.  Not really the answer I was looking for but close enough that I don't really want to be alive anymore.